# Правильно ли так мерять время, затраченное на вызов?

Tags: c++, std-chrono

Хочу сравнить время, затраченное на форматирование строки, используя библиотеку libfmt и старый добрый sprintf:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <chrono>
    using namespace std;

    #define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
    #include "fmt/format.h"

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;

        string str;
        int iters { 10000000 };
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point beg = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i { 0 }; i < iters; i++) {
            str = fmt::format("Now i is {}", i);
        }
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point fin { chrono::steady_clock::now() };
        chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed { fin - beg };
        cout << "elapsed: " << elapsed.count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
        cout << "time per iteration: " << elapsed.count() / (iters * 1.0) << " milliseconds" << endl;

        const int buf_size { 128 };
        char buf[buf_size];
        beg = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i { 0 }; i < iters; i++) {
            sprintf(buf, "Now i is %d", i);
        }
        fin = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed = fin - beg;
        cout << "elapsed: " << elapsed.count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
        cout << "elapsed per iteration: " << elapsed.count() / (iters * 1.0) << " milliseconds"  << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Нет ли тут методических ошибок? Корректно ли такое сравнение?

Comment: У вас начальное время для второго бенчмарка не обновляется.

Comment: Copy/paste подвел - не скопировал строчку, в оригинале она есть. Спасибо! А идея номальная?

Comment: В общем случае вполне подходящий метод.

Comment: Когда померяете, поменяйте местами два варината и попробуйте еще раз. И несколько запусков попробуйте.

Comment: И убедитесь, что слишком умный оптимизатор не выбросил все форматирования, кроме последнего в цикле... Вроде бы таких умных нет, но как знать?... :) Кстати, по времени вполне сравнимы, `format` чуть медленнее (VC++)/

Comment: Померял, запускал меняя местами. Разница - в единицах миллисекунд на 10000000 операций форматирования. В среднем 420 миллисекунд потребовала sprintf и 1515 миллисекунд libfmt.

Comment: Используйте профилировщик. Еще стоит убрать из теста пересоздание строки для fmt.

Comment: Какой компилятор и флаги? Оптимизация включена?

Comment: `g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-21)`, без оптимизаций, `g++ -o fmtsprint fmt-and-sprinf.cpp`

Comment: *"без оптимизаций"* - ну тогда это эпиф фейл

Comment: Можете что-то порекомендовать? В общем-то, поэтому я и спрашивал, как лучше.

Comment: Включайте оптимизации. И gcc обвите до 13 версии. Ну и то, что я писал в предыдущем коментарии.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Проблема только в том, что конечный код будет работать на stm32. Свой gcc обновить я могу, а вот на целевой платформе - проблематично. Впрочем, будем изучать. Большое спасибо за внимание и рекомендации!

Comment: Не думаю, что время форматирования может как-то сказаться на времени работы целевой программы (по крайней мере на том времени, которое критично для задачи, исполняемой этой программой на stm32) / Если у вас проблемы, то ищите их в другом месте

Comment: @avp - это же не вся программа :=), но если форматирование текста будет серьезно грузить микроконтроллер, тогда будет ресурс для решения проблем.

Comment: @Boris, форматированный текст вы куда выводите? Почти наверняка скорость устройства будет самым лимитирующим  фактором (сравните частоты процессора вашего stm и линии вывода)

Comment: @avp - пока это отладочный вывод в UART. Впоследствии его может и не быть. Поскольку это больше исследование, чем реальный проект, я хочу сравнить ресурсы, которые съедает форматирование текста.

Comment: @Boris, тогда лучше исследуйте прямо на stm и берите просто значения счетчика тактов (вроде бы от там называется DWT). Если не верите, то  распечатайте сотню измерений времени своего теста на  инструментальной машине и попробуйте честно объяснить самому себе все флуктуации

Comment: @avp, хорошо, спасибо за комментарии!